# Посоветуйте формат файла или програмку для ведения заметок по проектам

Tags: формат, проекты

По ходу занятия программированием веду различные проекты. Нужна программа, которая позволяла бы вести личные заметки по ним.

Требования (от простых - к сложным):

1. Только десктопная оффлайновая программа под Windows. Никаких онлайн сервисов, облаков и веб-сайтов.
2. Введение заметок текстом с клавиатуры в WYSIWIG редакторе, разметка если и требуется, то минимальная - шрифт жирный, наклонный, гиперссылка, заголовок.
3. Структурирование заметок. Обычное древовидное не подходит, так как зачастую одна запись логически соответствует двум и более родителям, так что нужны минимум теги. Очень хотелось бы, чтобы был удобный поиск по тегам и в идеале ведение самих тегов в виде иерархии (дерева).
4. Возможность вставлять картинки, таблицы, делать рядом пояснительные записи для тех и других, возможно, рисовать стрелки от них к тем элементам, которые они поясняют.
5. Создание шаблонов для групп записей (тегов). Например я хочу чтобы у всех записей в теге "моя программа" в верхней части было фиксированное именованное текстовое поле "название программы", которое я, понятное дело, заполняю вручную.
6. ! Возможность сформировать динамически обновляемую страницу, которая выводит в таблице или списке записи по определённому критерию (например тегу или времени создания). Причём выводит либо всю запись в виде раскрываемой по щелчку миниатюры, либо определённое именованное поле. Пример: я вывожу в таблице список всех записей из тега "проект", причём в первом столбце выводится именованное фиксированное поле "имя проекта", а во втором: "дата создания". Таблица автоматически обновляется при добавлении новой записи с тегом "проект". Есть возможность сортировки и фильтрации по любому полю.
7. Создание внутри записи ссылки на другую запись, например если между ними есть логическая связь и хочется это указать. Чтобы либо по щелку происходил переход, либо чтобы оригинал сразу вставлялся на страницу.
8. ! Возможность работы как визуально, через интерфейс, так и через API (буду писать скрипты). Особенно это необходимо, т.к. будет нужно получить уже упоминавшиеся выше именованные поля всех записей в некотором теге и как-то обработать их. Скрипты писать мне не важно на чём, но предпочтительно python.
9. Крайне желательна хорошая связываемость с продуктами от Microsoft. Чтобы в виде ссылки можно было вставить в запись письмо из Outlook, Word или Excel файл, чекин из Team Foundation Server или запись с определённым ключом из SQL Server.
10. Ну и вообще необходимо удобство, управление с клавиатуры (горячие клавиши) и максимальная автоматизируемость скриптами.

Если такой программы не существует - также рассматриваю возможность реализовать все функции самостоятельно, но тогда прошу посоветовать мне **формат файла**, который либо бы всё это вмещал в себе, либо бы, что ещё лучше, хранил бы заметки и вставляемые файлы (картинки, Word, Excel и тому подобное) в виде отдельных файлов на жестком диске, связывая их лишь какими-нибудь ссылками. Наверняка формат то такой точно кто-то уже придумал, очередной велосипед создавать очень не хочется.

Очень близка к требованиям Microsoft OneNote из пакета Office, но это софтина проприетаная и платная (не ведитесь на недавние сообщения, что она стала бесплатной, в этой версии урезаны некоторые функции), к тому же непонятно, как она будет вести себя с большим количеством сложных заметок. 
Но, повторюсь, из виденного мной она наиболее близка к идеалу.

Comment: @Richard:

a) А что плохого в проприетарности?

б) Если вы делаете коммерческие проекты, цена за максимальный MS Office не должна быть для вас чем-то существенным.

Answer (score 1):

Мое предложение - [zim](http://zim-wiki.org/).

1. да, это оффлайн. И не только под винду, а и под линукс. Формат хранилища совместимый.
2. да, есть минимальная разметка.  Работают классические комбинации Ctrl_B, Ctrl_I и подобные.
3. почти да. в основном все структурировано в дерево, но есть поддержка тегов.
4. картинки - да, таблицы - даже не знаю. Можно вставлять диаграммы (например Graphviz - очень удобно, так как диаграмма описывается текстом, а отрисовывается картинкой)
5. есть шаблоны - можно себе заготовить. Но я думаю, что я не совсем понял правильно задачу.
6. даже не знаю, есть списки задач, но можно попробовать и теги использовать.
7. да, внутренние ссылки есть.
8. все сохраняется в текстовых документах в очень простом формате. Так что можно редактировать и парсить сколько душа пожелает.
9. даже не знаю, зачем такое понадобиться, но можно написать свой плугин. Я к продуктам майкрософта отношусь с опаской.
10. управление с клавиатуры есть.

посмотрев на все, мне кажется, что вы хотите [Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence) или просто не узнали о [org режиме](http://orgmode.org/) emacs:)

Comment: @KoVadim, да zim - практически докувики получается :) Пока не очень понял, есть ли там вставка кода с подсветкой.

Comment: такого вроде нет. Но можно что то придумать.